# remote desktop on windows server 2012 issue

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

i installed windows server 2012 on my computer but when i connect to it remotely i can conncet  and use it for 2 or 3 minutes and after 2 or 3 minutes it hangs and i have to connect to it again.

i have poor connection quality but on same vps on this dedicated server which i installed windows server 2008 and windows server 2003 i can do what ever i want with no connection drop
is there any way to solve this issue

thanks in advance

Comment: What client are you using?  Server 2012 supports some of the newer options that are only supported using the Windows 8 client. (Dual Screen being one).

Comment: i use remote desktop connection.what should i use?

Comment: you should use what you are using, but my question was WHICH version of the client are you using?  Are you connecting from XP/Vista/7/8/2003/2008...etc?  Your issue might be related to compatibility issues between your client and the 2012 server.  Another thing have you tried changing the client experience setting to a less bandwidth intensive setting?

Comment: @MikeAWood my windows is windows 8.i used this settings too

Comment: I am on Windows 8 as well connecting back to Server 2012 too and haven't had that issue.  I thought maybe this might be something related to you using an older RDP client.  You might try looking in the Event log under Applications/Microsoft/Windows/RemoteDesktopServices/Operational and see if that helps point anything out.

Comment: @MikeAWood  can you please +1 me then i can post an answer for this ?? i found a solution for this problem and i think this will solve the problem of many people which will have this problem

Comment: @HiDd3N Did you let Windows chose the connection bandwidth or did you manual chose it?

Comment: i just turn udp to tcp because in some country udp traffic is blocked for political reason :)